# Android doze mode

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

In My app I'll use an Alarm to notify user for event, the problem is 
on Android version 6.x-
The alarm is delivered after same minutes of the exact times.
This is only when the device enter on sleeping mode.

I tried to wakelock the device before the alarm, but to no avail.

Can anyone help me? this is my code

**Set the alarms**

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        if (minutesBefore > 0) {
            beforeCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutesBefore);
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, beforeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), beforePendingIntent);
        }
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        if (minutesBefore > 0) {
            beforeCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutesBefore);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, beforeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), beforePendingIntent);
        }
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        if (minutesBefore > 0) {
            beforeCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutesBefore);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, beforeCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), beforePendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

**Weaklock**

> when i receive the alarm by broadcastreceiver im try to wake up device
>   from doze mode by this code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        //Object flags;

            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Alarm_WakeLock");

        wl.acquire();
```

But the alarm still delivered after same minutes!!

Comment: could you post your code please

Comment: Are you executing any network related operations after the alarm fired (e.g. in a service)?

Comment: no my service just display an activity as alarmActivity to inform user by few informations ..

Answer (score 1):

Doze mode is implemented to save the battery when the phone isn't used for some time. It does that by holding off operations like the AlarmManager.

If you really need the alarm to be fired in an exact time, use [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)).

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_doze) says:

> If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Comment: im tried it but nothing change, im update my question with my code look it

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions), it looks like setExactAndAllowWhileIdle will fire even during doze, so that should have worked for you but you can try setAlarmClock.

> Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

So you can use that. But it is intended to be used for what the user perceives as an alarm clock—a scheduled time at which the phone will alert the user (not just a calendar event). An icon is even displayed in the status bar as a physical alarm clock face, and many lockscreens will also inform the user of when the next alarm is scheduled.

ref
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/diving-into-doze-mode-for-developers/