# Android doze mode influence

Tags: android, doze

Have read a lot of documentation but did not find an answer for next question. If we have an app that should not be affected by doze (for example app with foreground service) will it also prevent other apps from being affected by doze? Point of question is if doze mode is something global for all applications (if it's enabled than all apps are affected) or it could affect some apps and don't affect other apps at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android doze mode and foreground service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804432/android-doze-mode-and-foreground-service)

Comment: Thanks but It's completely other question

Comment: How is it different? And it is a close vote, it is in the system now

Comment: Completely different, just read attentively. Question you mentioned is more like "does foreground prevent app from been affected by doze?" And my is like "If doze mode is prevented by one app will it affect other apps or not?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doze mode is global for all applications meaning all applications will be affected except for some few with a doze mode exemption.

Comment: that's not what he is asking